# Is it not possible to pass in a list to a lambda expression?

Tags: python

I am trying to print the squared values in a passed in list using a lambda expession.

```
squared = lambda x: x ** 2 
print(squared([1, 2, 3]))
```

This is the error that I am getting.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and
> 'int'

Comment: You're looking for `map` which applies a function to every element in some structure. In your example, `print(list(map(squared, [1,2,3])))`

Comment: It is possible to pass a list to a lambda function, but it is not possible to use a list with the `**` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the function to all elements in list.

```py
squared = lambda x: x ** 2 
print(list(map(squared,[1, 2, 3])))
```

One faster approach would be using numpy

```py
import numpy as np
print(np.array([1, 2, 3])**2)
```

EDIT:
another approach using list comprehensions

```py
def squared(list):
    return [i ** 2 for i in list]
print(squared([1,2,3]))
```

EDIT 2:
Here, I think you got confused between lambda and def because you have defined the functions differently.

Your current `def` function.

```py
def square (list1):
    list2 = [] 
    for num in list1:
        list2.append(num ** 2) 
    return list2 
print(square([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

The equivalent of this in lambda would be

```py
squared=lambda x:[y**2 for y in x]
print(squared([1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: I understand the use of map here. However I am trying to figure out the differences between a normal function and a lambda expression. Why is it that when defining a normal function as opposed to the lambda expression above, there is no need for map when calling the function. 

# Regular squared function

def square (list1):            
    list2 = []                 
    for num in list1:          
        list2.append(num ** 2) 
    return list2               
                               
                               
print(square([1, 2, 3, 4]))

Comment: its all about how you define a function using `def` and `lambda`. In the `def` way, you have defined a function which accepts a list and calculates the square of each element and returns the list of squares, but the `lambda` function you defined, is basically only for calculating square of an element. So you have to use `map` to apply it across all the elements in the list. Thats it.

Comment: @CalinParaipan I have updated the answer, I think this will clear your confusion. Please upvote the answer too if you found it helpful :D

Comment: Yes.I have seen that the equivalent of the code I sent you implies use of a `list` comprehension inside of a `lambda` expression. Close to what I've been thinking but not sure how to translate it to code.Thank you for clarifying the issue.

Comment: Happy coding :D

Answer (score 1):

`lambda x: doSomethingWith(x)` means that your function takes `x` as argument, and applies instructions to that argument. An "equivalent" code would be:

```
def f(x):
    return doSomethingWith(x)
```

The way you define `squared` means that your function takes as input a number and returns its square value. Which means you can't provide a list because your function definition takes a number as argument. There are multiple way you could use that on a list.

As others have mentionned, you could use map or list comprehension to "apply" your function on a list. That would mean that you're applying it to each element of the list (which is a number).

In case you want to use `squared([1,2,3])`, all you have to do is define a lambda function that takes a list as input and returns the squared of each number in that list. For instance you could use: `squared = lambda x: [i**2 for i in x]`.

This is all to say that lambda can take a list as argument, but it all depends on how you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You must map the lambda on the list, the pow (**) function expects a numeric type.

map takes a function and an iterable and returns a map object (which enables lazy computation), so if you want to get a list you can do

```
squared = lambda x: x ** 2
your_list = [1, 2, 3]
mapped_list = list(map(squared, your_list))
print(mapped_list)
```